# Will CyanogenMod run on the HTC ChaCha, and is it stable?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-chacha

Has anyone tried to install CyanogenMod on the HTC ChaCha? What is the level of compatibility I should expect from it with with CyanogenMod?

Comment: I didn't realize ChaCha has been rooted already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot just install CyanogenMod on any rooted device. It has to be one of the [supported devices](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices). There a lot of differences between builds of android and cyanogenmod for each device. They have different chipsets, gps, cameras, etc. They are always looking for other people to help support new devices though.

Answer (score 6):

We are working on SuperOSR, discussion here:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=18609103#post18609103

A full list of Cyanogen and other alternatives here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1698206

All ChaCha ROMs seem to have some bugs but otherwise quite stable. You could also take the latest official ROM and remove stuff you don't use. There are some already prepared, but you can also do such modifications yourself. Make sure to learn to use backup & restore before you start :)